# How to go to definition of a pytorch function in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytorch, vscode-remote

When I try the vscode remote SSH, I find that it can not go to definition of some pytorch function such as `torch.device`, but some function is normal such as `torch.tensor`.

Is it a error or it is normal for vscode? Thanks!